# JavaScript match current url against string with wildcards?

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to match the following string:

```
http://*/*/checkout
```

to this URL:

```
http://www.url.com/sub-folder/checkout
```

Ultimately what i am trying to do is to find a way to display my JavaScript widget on certain pages by allowing to add conditions like the above.

How could i use the string to see if the current URL matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex:

```
> /^http:\/\/.*?\/.*?\/checkout$/.test('http://www.url.com/sub-folder/checkout')
true
```

Here's a more readable version:

```
RegExp('^http://.*?/.*?/checkout$').test('http://www.url.com/sub-folder/checkout')
```